# cd won't work on this path. Any ideas?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, cd

In a section of a script I am writing, I output a list of paths into a temporary text file for use later with cd. I am using sed to replace spaces in directory names with '\ ' so that I also make the script work with spaces in dir names. My command is given below:
`cat temp.txt | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`
This has the desired output of replacing spaces with '\ ' but when I try to cd later it ignores the second word and says that example\ does not exist. Any ideas how to fix this?

My whole script is on pastebin here if you want to look at it: http://pastebin.com/6jmnKDAd

This is from a backup before I added sed

Comment: Can we see the following piece of code with cd?

Comment: give sample input and output from temp.txt

Comment: the input to temp.txt is from a recursive function that gets all the directories and subdirectories in a path. It would output each path on a new line. e.g. ~ [newline] ~/work and so on. I then perform the sed I gave above and store it in a variable called directories. I then use another function with a for loop to iterate over all paths. It looks something like `for a in $directories; do cd $a`

Comment: I also tried `cd "$a"` but that didn't fix it either

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is your **real** problem?

Comment: Use `sed 's/ /\\ /g' temp.txt`, there is no need for cat here.

Comment: Basically I'm writing a script to get files matching a regex from all the subdirectories of a specified path. If a 3rd arg is specified, it searches within the files for that word and prints the line it is found on. It works perfectly and only breaks when a directory name has a space in it :S The command is as follows `./script.sh pathHere regexHere optionalSearchHere`

Comment: Ive added a pastebin link to my code

Comment: Rather than trying to solve a problem that your code is creating, it's best to just not create the problem. See @GlennJackman's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To complement Lorenzo's answer, if you have a bunch of newline-separated pathnames in a file:

```
while IFS= read -r path; do
    cd "$path"
    do stuff
done < temp.txt
```

It is critical to quote `"$path"` to prevent the shell's [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)

Comment: I've modified my code to use this, but `cd` still gives me errors for names with spaces :/ it outputs something along the lines of "/pathHere/space test no such file or directory" though if i manually cd to the given path outside the script it works fine. any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps your text file has DOS line endings, so the $path variable ends with a carriage return. Try using `dos2unix` on your text file.

Comment: Ok Glenn, I've found that it works if I specify an absolute path i.e. it's fine with ~/path/..... but relative paths seem to be a no go e.g ./path doesnt work

Comment: In the context of your script, what is the `pwd`?

Comment: The pwd was just a random folder I had it in, I fixed it by changing back to the original path after each iteration of the while loop

Comment: Yes, I had the original search path stored in a variable called `startDir` so at the end of the loop I had `cd "$startDir"` and now it works fine :)

Answer (score 3):

Try enclosing your variable within " " without escaping blanks.

```
cd "$mydir"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this instead of `cat temp.txt | sed 's/ /\\ /g'`

```
perl -F"/" -ane 'foreach (@F){if(/ /){$_="\"".$_."\"";}}print join "/",@F;' temp.txt
```

also check [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2013/01/handling-directory-names-containing.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is there a need to use a temporary file or could you store the directories in an array:

```
dirs=()
dirs+=("/tmp/file A.txt")
dirs+=("/tmp/file B.txt")

for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
  cd "$d"
done
```

**Resources**

- man bash # type '/^ *Arrays' to search for the arrays section
- http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html

Comment: I've been asked to demonstrate knowledge of file IO so it needs to be done like this :S